# Demora en cargar el robo 3t

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb

Tengo un problema al momento de cargar mongod, se queda en  I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version:  y de ahi carga mas, entonces intento abrir el robot 3t y ni siquiera logro conectarme al mongodb local.
Alguien sabe que puede pasar?

Comment: Checa que version tienes de mongo instalada y con que versión es compatible el robo t3.

Comment: Si el servicio `mongod` no funciona, ¿Cómo pretendes que Robo3t se conecte?. Primero debes verificar que el servidor Mongo se carga correctamente. Saludos